Preview PDF files in React-Native application
In my react native application, I want to add a functionality to preview the PDF files. For that, I have an API url. When I open this url in the browser on desktop , it previews the Pdf file, but when I open this file in browser on my mobile, it starts downloading the file.
To preview the pdf, I am using 'react-native-webview'.
import WebView from 'react-native-web-view';

const PreviewPdf = () => {

  const [downloadPdf, setDownloadPdf] = useState(true);
  const [pdfPath, setPdfPath] = useState('');

  const openLink = (cn) => {
     const baseURL = 'http://192.168.2.81:7060/getCNToPreview';
     const url = `${baseURL}/${cn?.fileName}`;
 
     setDownloadPdf(true);
     setPdfPath(url);
  };

  return (
     <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress=() => openLink(cn)> View </TouchableOpacity>
           
        {
          (downloadPdf && pdfPath !== '') && <WebView source={{ uri: pdfPath }} style={styles.webView} />
        }
     </View>
  )
}

export default PreviewPdf;

In the openLink function, I am setting the url to preview the pdf. When the value of 'downloadPdf' is true and pdfPath is not "", it should open the source path of pdf file in .
When it opens the file path in Webview, it starts downloading the file instead of previewing it. How can I achieve the functionality of previewing the pdf file in my react-native application.

One way is to first download content to a local file using FileSystem.downloadAsync and then use Sharing to view it in any application capable of doing that (e.g. PDF reader). Something like this:
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';

const result = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
  'https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample.pdf',
  FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'sample.pdf'
);

if (result.status == 200) {
  Sharing.shareAsync(result.uri);
}

